# Как правильно реализовать уменьшение количества товара?

Tags: javascript, html

Работяги, добрый день! Пишу проект на html/sass/js, и столкнулся с такой проблемой как: есть две кнопки(уменьшить/увеличить количество товара), при нажатии на кнопку уменьшить визуально товар прибавляется, а переменная уменьшается(скрины будут ниже(извиняюсь за корявый скрин)). Хотел бы узнать почему так!

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.item-incr-button')
let btnDec = document.querySelectorAll('.item-decr-button')

let i = 1;

btnDec.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let btnId = btn.getAttribute('data-decr-id')
        let currentId = document.querySelector(btnId)
        currentId.innerText = i
        i--
        if(i === 0) {
            currentId.classList.remove('show')
        }
        console.log(i)
    })
})

btn.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        button.classList.add('add')
        button.innerText = ''
        let btnId = button.getAttribute('data-incr-id')
        let currentId = document.querySelector(btnId)
        currentId.innerText = i
        i++
        currentId.classList.add('show')
        console.log('incr')
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="page-item">
            <div class="item-counter" id="btn_1"></div>
            <div class="item-photo">
                <picture class="item-lottie">
                    <img src="src/image/Burger_148.png" alt="">
                    <source type="application/x-tgsticker" srcset="src/image/Burger_148.png">
                    <canvas width="74" height="74"></canvas>
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="item-label">
                <span class="item-title">
                    Burger
                </span>
                <span class="item-price">
                    $4.99
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="item-buttons">
                <button class="item-decr-button" data-decr-id="#btn_1">

                </button>
                <button class="item-incr-button" data-incr-id="#btn_1">
                    <span class="button-item-label">Add</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-item">
            <div class="item-counter" id="btn_2"></div>
            <div class="item-photo">
                <img src="src/image/Burger_148.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item-label">
                <span class="item-title">
                    Burger
                </span>
                <span class="item-price">
                    $4.99
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="item-buttons">
                <button class="item-decr-button" data-btn-id="#btn_2">

                </button>
                <button class="item-incr-button" data-btn-id="#btn_2">
                    <span class="button-item-label">Add</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Сам баг]

Comment: Для каждого товара у вас должен быть отдельный счетчик и обработчик.

Comment: Товаров планируется достаточно много, каждый раз генерировать новый обработчик?

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться делегированием. Но в вашем варианте счетчик общий, если вы прибавите другой товар, у него тоже будет значение от прошлого.

Comment: Тогда другой вопрос, как лучше реализовать счетчик? Что бы он не брал значение от другого товара

Comment: У вас должен быть какой-то объект аля cart.

Comment: Но я все так же не понимаю, почему визуально он прибавляет 1, а переменную уменьшает на 1?

Comment: Так вы сначала записываете в элемент значение, а потом отнимаете/прбавляете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Изначально у вас проблема была просто в том, что вы выводили значение счетчика до того, как его изменять.

```js
currentId.innerText = i
i--
// должно быть наоборот
i--
currentId.innerText = i
```

Получалось, что при клике на `-` у вас визуально увеличивалось, а по факту уменьшалось. Т.к. в вашей реализации вы сначала выводите `i` (то что получиолсь от предыдущего действия), а только потом его уменьшаете/увеличиваете.

2. В вашей реализации вы храните значение счетчика в одной общей для всех счетчиков переменной `i`. Как писали в комментариях, это приведет к тому, что при попытке изменить значение счетчика на одном товаре, оно по факту будет меняться для всех.
3. Не обязательно для каждой кнопки делать уникальный data-атрибут для id, можно обойтись просто `data-id` и для кнопки `-` и для `+`.
4. Вообще, я так понимаю, вы пытаетесь сделать нечно вроде корзины заказа. Если так, то вам надо хранить состояние корзины в отдельном объекте и работать с ним. Что-то типа такого:

```json
{
  "<id_tovara>": {"qty": "<kol_vo_tovara_v_zakaze", "size": "<razmer_porcii>"}
  "tov_1": {"qty": 1, "size": "large"},
  "tov_2": {"qty": 1, "size": "large"},
}
```

И потом еще сохранять этот объект корзины где-то либо в куках, либо в `localStorage`, чтобы не терять корзину при обновлении страниыц или переходе на другую.

---

Накидал примерчик, как то что вам нужно можно написать. Не идеально, кучу всего еще можно там улучшить. Так же в примере нет объекта корзины и сохранения состояния в куказ/хранилище. Это уже выходит за рамки вопроса :)

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('.item-incr-button')
let btnDec = document.querySelectorAll('.item-decr-button')

/// Отдельный метод для прибавления/убавления значения в счетчике
function addSubCounter(id, value) {
  let counter = document.querySelector(id)
  
  // На всякий случай, храним значение счетчика в data-атрибуте конкретного счетчика.
  // Его можно было бы брать и из innerText, но лучше не надо
  let qty = counter.getAttribute('qty') * 1 || 0
  
  // Сначала изменяем значение в счётчике,
  qty += value
  // потом делаем валидацию значения
  if (qty <= 0) {
    counter.classList.remove('show')
    qty = 0
  } else {
    counter.classList.add('show')
  }
  
  // и уже после этого делаем вывод и сохранение нового значения в data-атрибуте
  counter.innerText = qty
  counter.setAttribute('qty', qty)
}

btnDec.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let btnId = btn.getAttribute('data-id')
    addSubCounter(btnId, -1)
    console.log('decr')
  })
})

btn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.classList.add('add')
    button.innerText = ''
    let btnId = button.getAttribute('data-id')
    addSubCounter(btnId, 1)
    console.log('incr')
  })
})
```

```css
.item-counter {
  display: none;
}

.item-counter.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-item">
  <div class="item-counter" id="btn_1"></div>
  <div class="item-photo">
    <picture class="item-lottie">
      <img src="src/image/Burger_148.png" alt="">
      <source type="application/x-tgsticker" srcset="src/image/Burger_148.png">
      <canvas width="74" height="74"></canvas>
    </picture>
  </div>
  <div class="item-label">
    <span class="item-title">
                    Burger
                </span>
    <span class="item-price">
                    $4.99
                </span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-buttons">
    <button class="item-decr-button" data-id="#btn_1">

                </button>
    <button class="item-incr-button" data-id="#btn_1">
                    <span class="button-item-label">Add</span>
                </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page-item">
  <div class="item-counter" id="btn_2"></div>
  <div class="item-photo">
    <img src="src/image/Burger_148.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item-label">
    <span class="item-title">
                    Burger
                </span>
    <span class="item-price">
                    $4.99
                </span>
  </div>
  <div class="item-buttons">
    <button class="item-decr-button" data-id="#btn_2">

                </button>
    <button class="item-incr-button" data-id="#btn_2">
                    <span class="button-item-label">Add</span>
                </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не пишите транслитом, это ужасно!